# multishop + redirect

Tags: multistore, home-page

i need to create a redirect with a multistore

the code for a normal multishop is:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.pippo.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'pippo';
        $mageRunType = 'website';

            break;
    case 'www.utility.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'utility';
        $mageRunType = 'website';

            break;
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

But i want to go not
`www.pippo.com`
but
`www.pippo.com/en/`

maybe I should the run function...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use RewriteRule in **root folder/.htaccess**
And add this code.

```
</Files>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pippo\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pippo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.pippo\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]
</Files>
```